# SSRS: How to display a report title on the parameters page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My clients have upwards of 40 reports with very similar parameters.  These are hosted on SharePoint, but are consumed by users through a web application, and so when a report is selected and the parameters are shown, the report's title is lost.  My clients are irritated that they don't know, from the parameters page, which report is being displayed (many have very similar names and they are selected from a grid, and so mis-clicking is an issue)

[image]

Is there some trick to showing the report title on the parameters page?

Thanks

Edward

Comment: are the reports shown in a browser or some custom viewer? i can't imagine why the title isn't shown actually ...i have a lot of reports running with params and not a single one isn't showing the title

Comment: They are shown from within an ASP.NET application using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.

Comment: do u see the title when u collapse the params?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to add an additional parameter and show the report name in that.

Comment: That would work, but it's a bit of a kludge.  I was hoping for something more elegant :)

Comment: @Edwardo - how'd you conclude with this one? Did you make it a parameter? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Some points to highlight in your question.

First, I don't know any trick for showing the title in the parameter pane, as a matter of fact, I don't believe it does exist. Showing it as a parameter is something that I wouldn't do as a solution for a customer.

Second, not showing the little line with the report's path is something that can be chosen when invoking the report (by means of url, see links below) and if they are accessing through another web application, this should be the one taking care of this matter. Note that if you show the url or the little line with the path, you can compromise security (access will depend on folders setup, but you leave a door open). This web application should know what is it showing and should display the right name (any the actual report's name or a custom name within the web app). This is what happens when you embed SSRS reports using a browser in an external app.

Third, the report itself should have a title displayed once the report is executed.

As a summary, I don't believe this issue's solution is under SSRS management/development scope.

Links to know more about executing SSRS with an URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

As you can see, there are lots of things that you can do playing around with the url, such as:

1. Pass parameters
2. Hide path pane
3. Hide parameters pane
4. Render format, you can call an url asking for an excel or pdf render and you get the download dialog for the file.

Hope this helps.